# What would cause a request to be sent correctly in Chrome by GWT, but incorrectly in Safari and Firefox?

Tags: firefox, forms, gwt, google-chrome, safari

Im trying to submit a request and it is correctly handled in Chrome. Everything works correctly and I can keep moving through the workflow. The problem comes in when I try to send the request using Firefox or Safari. The request is simply not getting through correctly. Im trying to find where the error could occur, but I cant seem to figure out what would cause such a different behavior.

Im sending the request via a RequestBuilder and its pretty much the same code that I have been using throughout the entire project for all forms. My web browsers are the following and Im on **OS X 10.6.5**:
**Chrome 9.0.587.0 dev

Safari 5.0.2

Firefox 3.6.12**

Ive also tried on Windows 7 in Firefox. Has anyone ever run into a problem like this and if you have, have you found a fix? Thank you!

Edit:

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, "/deployments/" + createdProjectName + "/");
    builder.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try {
      Request request = builder.sendRequest(formBuilder.toString(), new RequestCallback() {
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            //I handle an error here
        }

        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            if( response.getText().contains("Back to") ){
                //Successful handling here
            } else {
                //Handling more errors here
        }});
    } catch (RequestException e) {

    }
```

Comment: Define "submit a request". Can you show some code?

Comment: Im sending a POST request. Ive updated above to show how I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem!

The backend was refusing to handle the request because GWT decided to tack on a charset for the header data and we were not checking for that charset, we were just checking the content type. A one line fix to the backend solved all our problems.